# Select last duplicate row in MySQL

Tags: mysql

SELECT Duplicate row item from MySQL table using

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY `col1`,`col2` Having COUNT(`col1`)>1 and COUNT(`col2`)>1
```

**Actual result**

[image: Actual result]

The above query return first duplicate entry. from above data row 1 and row 7 contains duplicate field in same column(col1, col2).

But I need to Get last duplicate entry. Highlighted duplicate row

**Expected Result**

[image]

Comment: "Last" duplicate entry with regard to _which_ column?  Can you add sample data to your question?

Comment: sample data added. in image i need highlighted row in yellow color

Comment: How to you define the *last* duplicate? You need a column to order the results, there is no inherent order in a database table.

Comment: To recap, rows in rdbms tables represent unordered sets. There is no 'first'. There is no 'last'.

Comment: let us consider id column for first and last duplicate entry

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get last duplicate entry.

How do you define the *last* duplicate? In a database table, records are not inhenrently ordered, and you did not tell which column we should use for ordering.

*If* you want to order by `col3`, then you can just use aggregation, like so:

```
select col1, col2, max(col3) -- or min(col3)
from mytable
group by col1, col2
-- having count(*) > 1       
-- uncomment the above line if you want to see only records for which a duplicate exists
```

If you have some other column that you want to order with, say `id`, then you can filter with a correlated subquery

```
select col1, col2, col3
from mytable t
where id = (
    select max(id) from mytable t1 where t1.col1 = t.col1 and t1.col2 = t.col2
)
```

Comment: i have more than 90000 row items in my table it took long time. but result not coming.

Comment: @vinothvk: are you running the first query or the second query?

Comment: second query select col1, col2, col3
from mytable t
where id = (
    select max(id) from mytable t1 where t1.col1 = t.col1 and t1.col2 = t.col2
)